# Load SWF and override existing library symbols

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, swfloader

I have Main.fla and SkinA.fla. Both have MovieClip library item: MC_BrandLogo.
I'm loading the  SkinA.swf into Main.swf in the current application domain trying to replace the class inside Main.swf. If there is no library item in the Main.fla, I can instantiate MC_BrandLogo with the correct graphic. If the MC_BrandLogo already exist in the Main.fla then that graphic is used even though I loaded new one in the current application domain.
Is there a way to replace existing linked movie clips with loaded dynamically?

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSkinLoaded);
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
loader.load(new URLRequest("SkinA.swf"));

function onSkinLoaded(e:Event):void {
    trace("loaded Skin");
    addChild(new MC_BrandLogo());
}
```

EDITED: There is no way to override the images I was trying to override, because this is how application domains work. If the definitions exist in the parent application domain, they are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can not overwrite a Class Definition in an ApplicationDomain unless you wish to resort to [manipulating bytecode at runtime](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/index.html).

What you can do, however, is load your skin SWF into a child Application Domain and then retrieve the appropriate Class Definition (symbol) via [ApplicationDomain.getDefinition](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#getDefinition%28%29); ie:

```
private var _skinAppDomain : ApplicationDomain;

function loadSkin() : void {
    // Keep a reference to the Skin's application domain.
    _skinAppDomain = new ApplicationDomain();

    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, _skinAppDomain);

    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSkinLoaded);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("SkinA.swf"));
}

function onSkinLoaded(e:Event) : void {
    var brandLogoSymbolName : String = "MC_BrandLogo";

    // Retrieve the symbol from the Skin's Application Domain directly.
    var brandLogoClipClazz : Class = _skinAppDomain.getDefinition(brandLogoSymbolName);

    // Check we have the symbol.
    if (brandLogoClipClazz == null) {
        throw new Error("Skin SWF must include a symbol named: " + brandLogoSymbolName);
    }

    addChild(new brandLogoClipClazz());
}
```

To help debug missing symbol names in ApplicaitonDomains you can list all Class Definitions (symbols) contained by using [SWF Explorer](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=175).

Comment: Can somebody confirm that this works? I've tried that and I can't make it work.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer even though it doesn't work for me just to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

Beaten to the punch. JonnyReeves is correct I believe. A good discussion on this topic can be found here:

[Application Domains on Senocular](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/contentdomains/?page=2)

Comment: Senocular's article is a Great reference; I should have included it in my answer, Wes!

Comment: For sure, it's certainly a lot less confusing than Adobes own information on this topic. I think you nail the crux of it though.

Comment: @JonnyReeves, I've tried your method but it doesn't work. <br/>
1) ApplicationDomain don't have "getDefinitionByName" but "getDefinition"<br/>
2) using _skinAppDomain.getDefinition returns null for MC_BrandLogo and I'm sure it's linked in the SkinA.swf. Adding the whole loader shows the logo correctly<br/>
3)loader.content.loaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition(brandLogoSymbolName) as Class; is getting the non-null definition but it's the Main's logo placeholder.

Comment: @WesLastLevel, I've read that article (in fact I had it opened while writing the question) and it works when you don't have placeholder in the Main.swf, but my question is about using both placeholder and new graphics together.

Comment: @PlamenAndreev If the class definition is not being found in `SkinA.swf` then I'm guessing you have not created the correct linkage in the Flash Authoring Environment when the SWF was published.  SWF Explorer is a library for listing all classes contained in an Application Domain which might come in useful: http://www.bytearray.org/?p=175

Comment: @JonnyReeves, I'll test and see what SWFExplorer traces out. Here is the link to my settings in Flash IDE: http://screencast.com/t/MxaKT9qMHp

Comment: @JonnyReeves, I've tested loading the SkinA.swf in a new flash document with the following code: http://screencast.com/t/5zGEN23nKO8q. Output: MC_BrandLogo   MC_BrandLogo   1. Also, I changed the name of the linkage to make sure that it's the correct linkage to "skin.MC_BrandLogo" and it traces fine again. Do you know why the _skinAppDomain.getDefinition returns null?